# How to display code coverage for business layer in SonarQube Dashboard

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am new to Jenkins and SonarQube configuration. Wanted to display the code coverage of PCs layer of the project in SonarQube Dashboard. (Test cases are written using MS test framework)
Facing a problem as SonarQube Dashboard is showing 0% coverage inspite of having 40 + test cases for PCs layer. 
Following are the ‘Build’ configuration:
[image: Build Config from Jenkins Job]

Part 2:
[image]

SonarQube Dashboard
[image]

Assuming the probable cause – the sonarqube dashboard showing results of WebProject(as highlighted in screenshot) and not for the business layer. Need help in showing coverage of Business Layer of the Project(PCs as highlighted in screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This after months I was able to resolve. As the requirement was to achieve code coverage for Business layers like PC's as highlighted in above question. This was fixed by following the below steps:

**Sonar plugin order should be:**

1. Execute Windows batch command - to delete the .trx or .coveragexml files
2. SonarQube Scanner for MSBUILD - Begin Analysis
3. Build a VS project or solution using MSBUILD
4. Run Unit test with VSTest.console
5. Execute windows batch command- to convert the test report from trx to coveragexml
6. SonarQube Scanner for MSBUILD -End Analysis

*Note:* Make sure to **Run Unit test with VSTest.console** and not with MS Test

**Change the path in windows batch command plugin to delete the test result file**

```js
d:\jenkins\tools\nuget\nuget.exe restore "%WORKSPACE%\<Project>.sln"

if exist TestResults\ del TestResults\*.trx

if exist TestResults\ del TestResults\*.coveragexml
```

**Changed the path of the unit test dll to - "Bin\.UnitTest.dll".**

Answer (score 0):

You have 24k lines of code and 40 unit tests? The coverage percentage likely comes in at <1%... less than .5% even. So that's being rounded to 0%.

If you want to narrow it down, you can [set exclusions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreCodeCoverage) for the stuff you don't want included in the coverage calculation (you'll have to re-analyze after making the updates for them to take effect) but you'll still likely weigh in around 0% until you add more tests.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Yes i want to narrow down the scope as we are writing test cases only for PCs layer and not for 24k line Web project.  Do I need to have admin privileges in SonarQube to **set exclusions**?

Comment: Even after excluding the web project, code coverage percentage is displaying 0%